# Can you please identify these DC characters?

Tags: dc, character-identification

[image]

I can identify only these characters from the image above..

Top row (the hero row):

1. ??? (Someone from Thundercats?)
2. Green Arrow (not 100% sure)
3. Flash
4. Wonder Woman
5. Superman
6. Batman
7. Green Lantern
8. Martian Manhunter (not 100% sure)
9. Aquaman
10. Cyborg (not 100% sure)

Bottom Row (the villain row):

1. ??? (I remember a ghost villain from Thundercats cartoon, but I can't recall his name)
2. ???
3. Captain Cold
4. Cheetah (Barbara Ann Minerva)
5. Lex Luthor (if villians on bottom row match with superheroes from top row)
6. ??? (Looks Riddler to me)
7. Yellow Lantern (maybe, Sinestro)
8. ???
9. ???
10. ???

Can you please identify them?

Comment: If you are copying these from a source website, you should be linking that source.

Comment: @Skooba As I said on the other post, I am getting these on social media..

Comment: Top row are the heroes and the bottom row are their respectives nemeses. Pretty easy to even go with a guess :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Top row (the hero row):

1. Hawkman
2. Green Arrow
3. Flash
4. Wonder Woman
5. Superman
6. Batman
7. Green Lantern
8. Martian Manhunter
9. Aquaman
10. Cyborg

Bottom Row (the villain row):

1. [Shadow Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Thief)
2. Count Vertigo
3. Captain Cold
4. Cheetah (Barbara Ann Minerva)
5. [Lex Luthor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_Luthor)
6. Joker
7. Sinestro
8. [Malefic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27alefa%27ak)
9. Black Manta
10. Deathstroke

Community wiki to aggregate answers from other posts, including the original question.  Feel free to edit in corrections or URLs.  Don't forget to upvote the sources.

Comment: I love Community Wikis! Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

Each one, with a bit of an hair-split for one, is an enemy of the hero in the top shot.

B-1 is the [Shadow Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Thief). B-8 is [Malefic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27alefa%27ak), twin brother of J'onn J'onzz.

B-10, Deathstroke the Terminator, was a recurring enemy of the (new) Teen Titans, of which Cyborg was a founding member.

Answer (score 1):

How do you miss the Joker (B-6) and Sinestro (B-7) much less confuse him up with Abin Sur?

B-8 not idea, but B-9 is Black Manta, B-10 Deathstroke. B-2 is Count Vertigo, while I have no idea who B-1 is. T-1 is Hawkman.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I actually meant Sinestro.. BTW, is that Joker or Riddler?

Comment: By emblem and standing on a spring board, yes, it Joker. Otherwise question marks would have been used.

Comment: Yes, first one looks like Hawkman.. I mistook the symbol for Thundercats (which may not even be DC).. :)

Comment: Because Riddler is generally known for carrying a cane and Joker generally is not.

Answer (score 0):

Top 1 is Hawkman. Yes Top 2 is Green Arrow

Comment: Could you possible extend this answer to include all the possibilities?